# Trigger onEdit (e): popup with a warning when any cell in the column changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

It is necessary that when changing any cell in the "E" column to "Enabled", if there is an empty cell "B" and "C" or "D" in this row, a warning window with the "OK" button will pop up.
That is, the "Enabled" status is allowed if the line contains: 1) "B, C"; 2) "B, D"; 3) "B, C, D".
Over time, there will be more than a thousand of lines on the sheet.
I tried to write a script, but nothing comes out.[image]

```
    function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Лист1')
  var cellIvalue = sheet.getRange('E2:E').getValue();
  var cellBvalue = sheet.getRange('B2:B').getValue();
  var cellCvalue = sheet.getRange('C2:C').getValue();
  var cellDvalue = sheet.getRange('D2:D').getValue();
  
  if (cellIvalue == 'Включено'&& cellBvalue.CELL_EMPTY)
    
  {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var message = ui.alert(
      'Alert text"',  
  ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you find `cellBvalue.CELL_EMPTY` ?

Comment: @TheMaster I didn't bother asking. Also `ui` is not defined anywhere. He gets the full array of columns and compare it with a single string (which by the way is not enable). Many issues. At least he tried something :p.

Comment: @Marios Yes there are many issues and it's still better than "I need this and this.. Do it for me within 1 day". I still don't think it should've been answred(though I did;)). PS: `ui` is defined: `var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();`

Comment: @TheMaster yes true, my bad. I voted up your answer. I am not sure if the OP understands it, but **I**  learnt from it :)

Comment: @АртурПетров I still believe it'll be useful if you asked a simple question. For eg: 1.`cellBvalue.CELL_EMPTY`. Question like "How do I find if a cell is empty from apps script?" In another post, 2. "How do I figure out the context of  execution? Which cell is edited from `onEdit()`?" Simple questions like that will help you more as well as the community. For studying, All you need is the "official documentation" and **practice**. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more  resources.

Comment: You don't need to apologise, you are just doing more than fine and way better than many people that ask questions here. The most important part of learning is to try. Many people just ask codeless questions. You did just fine :)

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/ (Breaking apart helps). For sample great questions, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript%2barrays?tab=Votes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the following **three** scenarios for which **Enable** would **fail**:

1. **B, C, D** are **all** blank,
2. **B** is blank, but either **C** **or** **D** is not,
3. **B** is not blank, but both **C** **and** **D** are blank.

Therefore, you must be looking for this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  if(as.getName() == 'Лист1' && col == 5 && row > 2 && e.range.getValue() == 'Enable'){
    
    if(as.getRange(row,2).isBlank() && as.getRange(row,3).isBlank() && as.getRange(row,4).isBlank() ){
     var message = "Enter data into the cell:\n 'Start date'\n and\n 'Expiration date' or 'Amount'";
     }
    else if (as.getRange(row,2).isBlank() && (!as.getRange(row,3).isBlank() || !as.getRange(row,4).isBlank()) ){
     var message = "Enter data into the cell:\n 'Start date'";
     }
    else if (!as.getRange(row,2).isBlank() && as.getRange(row,3).isBlank() && as.getRange(row,4).isBlank()){
     var message = "Enter data into the cell:\n 'Expiration date' or 'Amount'";
     }
    if(message){
        ui.alert(message, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
        as.getRange(row,col).clearContent();
    }     
    }
  }
```

Comment: Greetings, Marios. And again you. I am very grateful for your help. Everything turns out thanks to such responsive people as you and this forum. I am very happy about it.
A small question, if I may.
How to make it impossible to switch the value in a cell to "Enable" until you fill in the blank cells?

Answer (score 2):

#### Flow:

- Get edited `v`alue , `r`ow and `c`olumn  from [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- `return`, if restricting conditions like sheet name, row number etc aren't satisfied
- [`offset`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns) the edited `r`an`g`e to the left to find B,C and D
- `showAlert` if B is empty or both of C and D are empty.

#### Sample script:

```
'use strict';
/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} param1
 */
function onEdit({
  value: v,
  range: { rowStart: r, columnStart: c },
  range: rg,
}) {
  /*Exit code*/
  if (
    v !== 'Enable' ||
    r < 2 ||
    c !== 5 ||
    rg.getSheet().getName() !== 'Sheet1'
  )
    return;

  const [[startDate, expirationDt, amount]] = rg
      .offset(0, -3, 1, 3)
      .getValues(),
    showAlert = () => {
      const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.alert('Invalid Data', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    },
    isEmpty = e => e === '';

  //if startDate is empty or both expirationDt & amount is empty, showAlert and clear range
  if (isEmpty(startDate) || [expirationDt, amount].every(isEmpty)){
    showAlert(); 
    rg.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, TheMaster. Your version of the script also works.
The only thing is, ``rg.clear ()`` does not work if I understood correctly that this should erase cell "E".

Comment: @АртурПетров Edited my answer. Try now.